# Access columns dynamically

Tags: vba, ms-access

following question: i have a db where a columns' entries are equal to one of the column names. can i compare the values and store the contents of the matching column?

Ex.:
suppose there are columns **col1, col2** and **col3** with values *1,2* and *3* respectively. I want to compare the names of the columns (**col1** to **col3**) with the contents of another column (let's call it **aggrcol**) and if they are equal, store the value of the column in **aggrcol**. is there a way to do that in access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Use VBA and a recordset, loop through this, and for each record check:

```
If Val(Right(rs.SomeField.Name, 1)) = rs.SomeField.Value Then
    ' Content matches name index.
    ' Update field aggrcol.
    rs.Edit
        rs!aggrcol.Value = rs.SomeField.Value + rs.SomeOtherField.Value
    rs.Update
End If
```